# How to addition of all the elements of an array of type string which contains only float values

Tags: java

I am new to Java, I have a string [] array = [1234.56,567.78,456.78]

I wants to do "Sum" of all the above values.

I tried :

```
private void processLine(String[] strings) {

    Integer[] intarray=new Integer[strings.length];

    int i=0;

    for(String str:strings){

        intarray[i]=Integer.parseInt(str.trim());//Exception in this line

        i++;

    }

}
```

But getting error "numberformateexception"

Comment: The easiest approach would mean you would have to use a `for` loop and a `Float.parseFloat(String str)`....

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you plz help me with an example

Comment: private void processLine(String[] strings) {

    Integer[] intarray=new Integer[strings.length];

    int i=0;

    for(String str:strings){

        intarray[i]=Integer.parseInt(str.trim());//Exception in this line

        i++;

    }

}

Comment: @Alok Tiwari Tiwari  Go and study wrapper class . And read documentation to learn how to ask a question.

Comment: I have tried above

Comment: You said you have Float values and u r using Integer array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double sum = 0; //use a double instead of a float
for (String str : strings)
{
    sum += Double.parseDouble(str); //same as: sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(str);
    //+= means: add the value from the right of the operator (+=) to the left
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you're certain that values are going to be one data type (such as `float`), it's considered best practice to store those in an array of that data type - such as:
`float[] floatValues`

For the solution to your current problem, take a look at how to use a [`for`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_for_loop.htm) loop in Java. Use these to loop through your `float` values and add them together using the `+` operator.

If you have a "total" `float` variable, you'll be able to add each individual `float` value to it in a function which can then return said "total" variable to give the sum of the numbers specified.

If it's a requirement to store the values as a `string[]`, as mentioned in the comments by npinti, you can use Java's [`Float.parseFloat(string)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat(java.lang.String)) function to return the float equivalent of your string.

Also, just to note: an `Integer` (or `int`) is a **whole** number. If you attempt to parse a float value as an integer, it will throw a runtime exception because it's been given an invalid parameter. A `float` value however is **not** a whole number and can go into decimal values. For this reason, because you're using non-whole numbers, you will need to use the `float` data type (alternatively [`double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)).

Comment: Also, thank you for the detailed information .. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to convert string values into float `//Float.valueOf(YouString)`

```
float Sum = 0;

for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
Sum = Float.valueOf(array[i]) + Sum;
}
// 
//SUM contains addition of all float values of Array.
```